# Unknown error with Paperclip and ImageMagick - Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick

I am using **PaperClip** and **ImageMagick** to upload and generate images in my **Rails 2.2.2** application.

It was working fine. But now when uploading image, the different sizes of image which gets generated at the time of upload is not working. The image is getting uploaded.

I am getting the following error in log.

```
 INFO  production : [paperclip] /usr/local/bin/identify -format "%w" /www/hosts/{path}

 INFO  production : <Paperclip::PaperclipCommandLineError> Error while running identify

 /www/hosts/{path}/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:101:in `run'
```

I can't understand what is happening here. I checked the path of identify using `which identify` which returned `user/local/bin/identify`.

The Paperclip in config is as

```
Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin'
```

Any idea what is happening here??

I tried to add a Paperclip custom validation to the model. I think the image upload went wrong after this validation. I have removed it. But still not working.

This is the line of code which stops it all in square_up function.

`Paperclip.run('identify', args).strip`

The Paperclip is not able to process image.img format.

The symlink master.img is not generated properly. A symlink is created as master.png and it points to master.img. The symlink should be master.img which points to the real image uploaded.

Comment: Is this `/www/hosts/{path}` by any chance meant to be `/www/hosts/#{path}` ?  (note extra # for string interpolation)

Comment: I just used it to cover my project name. That is not the issue.

Comment: Curious. Whats the file name? was this feature working before and broke recently

Comment: This was working before. I think it has something to do with the custom validation I added. I have removed it and restarted apache.

Comment: @Coderhs The thumbnails are not getting generated. And I think the identify error is happening because the image is not present. But I can't figure out why the images are generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled ImageMagick from source. The decode delegate libraries for jpeg and png were missing. Installed them individually by `yum install libpng libpng-devel` and `yum install libjpg libjpg-devel` .

After that reinstalled ImageMagick and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like issue with your imagemagick installation. Try find if you have properly installed imagemagick or not, Try run `convert` on console.

```
$ convert
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

You should get result something like above.
If you get above result try upgrade imagemagick version.

libtool also cause such errors, SO try install `libtool` also.

Hope this works.

Comment: When I run `convert` I get `Version: ImageMagick 6.4.8-10 2015-05-23 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC`

Comment: So you are on latest version of imagemagick. Try install `libtool` then.

Comment: If I try to upgrade the current ImageMagick version, it will not be compatible with the Rails version. It was working perfectly fine till now.

Comment: try run `identify path/to/any/image` If you get any error then this problem due to libtool.

Comment: Package libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version.

Comment: When running that, I'm getting `JPEG 116x116 116x116+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 3.95kb ` for the checked image. Not any error